# Likelihood principle: difference between weak and strong version

Tags: likelihood, likelihood-principle

Does anyone understand the difference between weak likelihood principle and strong likelihood principle?

Comment: The hits in [Google searches for "weak likelihood principle"](https://www.google.com/search?q="weak+likelihood+principle") show that the answer is yes.

Comment: Perhaps you could say what you don't understand about it.

Comment: ... then the answer may be more useful to you (& perhaps  to others, perhaps even to the answerer) than one that trots out the usual explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's straightforward. The weak LP is within a given model and distribution (it's essentially just the sufficiency principle within a model), whereas the strong LP, SLP, makes the claim (of equivalent evidential import) for pairs of models. Easiest to refer to my paper here: http://errorstatistics.com/2014/09/06/statistical-science-the-likelihood-principle-issue-is-out

fortunately, it turns out the the SLP does not follow from sufficiency and conditionality, as had long been thought.

Comment: Could you please also give a complete reference? Links have a habit of dying.

Comment: You say that the SLP does not follow from sufficiency and conditionality, but in fact Mayo's disproof of Birnbaum's proof has been seriously challenged and may well be flawed. https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08093